# C# Serilog config in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, serilog

I have the following in `appsettings.json` for Serilog:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning" //Amik ezekből a névterekből jönnek is Informationok lesznek.
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ]
  },
```

I tried to add Serilog for my bootstrap app, but nothing worked well :(.

It is not logging to the console.

Comment: You don't have a 'Using' element with the 'Serilog.Sinks.Console' in your appsettings.json file. This makes me think you also didn't reference the 'Serilog.Sinks.Console' NuGet package in your project. Once this is done then you have to load the Serilog configuration from the settings file and configure the host to use Serilog. Here's a simple example on using Serilog with the console... [Serilog - Getting Started](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: U had right too. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the following settings in appsettings.json for Serilog. I tried to add Serilog for my bootstrap app, but nothing worked well
> It is not logging into console.

Well, its not quite clear if you have followed all the steps accordingly. Based on your shared [`appsettings.json`](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example/blob/dev/appsettings.json) it appreared that your configuration is partially correct. If you don't define anything inside using block its better to ommit that. In addition to this, you haven't defined your "Args" parameter where need to log what I mean is the path. Furthermore, whether you have install the required [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/) and included the required code snippet in your program.cs file

Therefore, you can follow the steps below to implement it correctly.

**Prerequisite:**

1. Serilog Nuget Package
2. appsettings.json  [configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics)

**1. Serilog Nuget Package**

To configure Serilog for asp.net core reagrdless of its version, you need to following package in your application reference.

```
serilog.aspnetcore, serilog.aspnetcore and serilog.expressions
```

You can add from your Nuget Package Manager as following:

[image]

Once all the required package installed accordingly it should look like below:

[image]

In addititon, you even can using nuget package manager console command which are like below:

```
dotnet add package serilog.aspnetcore
dotnet add package serilog.sinks.seq
dotnet add package serilog.expressions
```

**2. appsettings.json  configuration**

Please replace your [appsettings.json](https://procodeguide.com/programming/aspnet-core-logging-with-serilog/) file as following for serilog.

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
   
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
      
    ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Program.cs file**

```
using Serilog;



Log.Logger =  new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console().CreateBootstrapLogger();
Log.Information("Staring up logging");

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, logConfig) => logConfig
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();



    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    Log.Fatal(ex,"Unhandled Exception");
}

finally
{
    Log.Information("Log Complete");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details about [logging in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#built-in-logging-providers) you could [check the official document here](https://github.com/datalust/dotnet6-serilog-example#setting-up-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me in .net 7

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders().AddSerilog(CustomLoggerConfiguration.Configure());
```

**CustomLoggerConfiguration**

```
 public class CustomLoggerConfiguration
{
    public static Logger Configure()
    {
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
              .MinimumLevel.Information()
              .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
              .Enrich.FromLogContext()
              .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day).CreateLogger();
    }

}
```